# How to debug HTTP ERROR 500 on Ubuntu Apache2 AWS EC2 Laravel Project

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, apache, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I have problem with my laravel project which was on AWS EC2 instance.*emphasized text*

I did "Reboot Instance" on AWS EC2 instance. It was working fine before reboot.

After reboot default apache2 page appeared.

I edited `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` file from;

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
```

to;

```
DocumentRoot /home/ubuntu/my-laravel-oproject-folder/public
```

where my project was on.

After that the error was turned to `403 Forbidden` . I tried `sudo chmod -R 775 /home/ubuntu/my-laravel-oproject-folder/public` and i edited `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` file from;

```
<Directory /var/www>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

to;

```
<Directory /home/ubuntu>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

After these changes now i get `HTTP ERROR 500` .

I restarted apache with `sudo service apache2 restart` after every changes.

Iam new to programming and I have no experience on aws or server settings so any idea would be welcome.

If you want me to give more details or share specific files just leave a comment.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `/var/www/html` seems to be a good place to host your sites. Why did you change that?

Comment: @LajosArpad it was not me :(. i do not know why :(

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you will need to make sure that the folder where your project is located is matching the `Directory` and `DocumentRoot`.

Secondly, your site will be loaded by some user, in Ubuntu this user is `www-data`. This user needs to have access privileges to your project files, otherwise you will have a hard time using them.

This is why it seems that your solution is as follows:

## 1. Move the project folder to an appropriate place

Make sure that you move your project to an appropriate place, such as **/var/www/html/MyProject**. (rename MyProject or choose a different path as you like)

## 2. Grant access privileges

Your `www-data` user needs to be able to access the project files. Alternatively, you can make another user the owner of the files, but then you will need to make sure that the user owns it:

```
sudo chown -R www-data /var/www/html/MyProject
```

or

```
sudo chown -R youruser:www-data /var/www/html/MyProject
```

but then make sure your user exists and has the `www-data` role. This is how you can find out what users are members of the `www-data` group:

```
grep ^www-data /etc/group
```

And this is how you can add a user to the `www-data` group:

```
sudo adduser youruser www-data
```

## 3 Change the configuration

Look for the configuration file inside `/etc/apache2/sites-available` and make sure you have a proper config, that is, you define `DocumentRoot` so that it will point to the correct location as well as the `Directory` tag should point to the correct location, like

```
<Directory /var/www/html/MyProject>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

## 4. Make sure you have the right config

In general, each site is good to have its own config file, so you could

```
cp 000-default.conf yoursite.conf
```

## 5. Enable your site

If your site was already enabled, then you can run

```
sudo a2dissite yoursite
```

in order to disable it. Then, running

```
sudo a2ensite yoursite
```

enables it.

## 6 Restart Apache

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2.service
```

Comment: First of all thank you for answer! I followed all steps, i had no error during running commands but unfortunately it did not work and i am getting same error at the end. i tried that i changed `index.php` file name to `index.php.bak` and get that index page [click](https://i.ibb.co/2jLkJqv/Ekran-Resmi-2023-09-12-17-01-15.png)

Comment: HTTP 500 means that something went wrong. You will need to check the server logs to find out more details about the error. It could be anything. It could be PHP error as well. Please check the logs and tell me what is the elaborate error that you can find.

Comment: @MustafaArslan did you generate laravel app key?